# Reusable, abstracted way to bind multiple lexicals all in one go

Tags: perl

I have code that repeats this pattern:

```
sub method1 {
    my ($foo, $bar) = _get_things();   # this line...
}

sub method2 {
    my ($foo, $bar) = _get_things();   # ...is repeated here
}
```

The repeated line is just one line, so in a sense repeating it is no big deal.  But, that has the drawback that if the list `($foo, $bar)` ever changes, all these lines need to change.  In C, one might use the preprocessor to solve this problem.  Is there a good idiom for doing it in Perl?  Something like the following psuedo-perl:

```
MACRO_DEFINITION  my ($foo, $bar) = _get_things();

sub method1 {
    MACRO_CALL
    print "hi $foo";
} 

sub method2 {
    MACRO_CALL
    print "hi $foo and $bar";
}
```

note: the reason `_get_things()` returns a list that I am binding to local lexical scalars is that I want to use them in string interpolation, as the latter example shows.

Comment: I can think of several awful solutions, but no good ones.

Comment: "if the list ($foo, $bar) ever changes, all these lines need to change" The obvious solution is to have `_get_things()` return a hashref or an object so the order doesn't matter, but you've ruled that out. Why?

Comment: Do the methods then go on to use these names, `$foo` and `$bar`?  If that is the case then I'd start with refactoring that.  It would mean that the methods should have another level of abstraction.  Or, why are the names themselves important (if this is about names)?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I guess the only reason is string interpolation - I  want to write `"hello $foo !"` and not `"hello " . $things{foo} . " !"` or use the turtle operator or some such.

Comment: Hash values interpolate: `"hello $things{foo}!"`

Comment: Well, how about that :)  I've edited the question to specify the reason I did not want to use a hash.  If you copy that comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @gcbenison: It would be better if `_get_things` returned a hash *reference* as in the answer from ysth below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a sub has more than a very few parameters, or what the parameters are is possibly going to change, you should pass a hash or hashref to emulate named parameters.

All the more so here, where you are returning more than one result and what the results are is *likely* to change, you should return a hashref from the sub.  And just use that hashref in the caller (yes, even in string interpolation.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub method2 {
    my $thing = _get_things();
    print "hi $thing->{'foo'} and $thing->{'bar'}\n";
}

sub _get_things {
    return {
        'foo' => 42,
        'bar' => 'quux',
    };
}

method2();
```